# GETTEXT returns null value (Class-TSortGrid)

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke, autoit-c#-wrapper

I have been trying to get the text of a gridview.I used autoit tool to get the instance and class of the view https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyev3.png

The Code i have used to get the instance of the TsortGrid is as follow

```
      using System;
      using System.Collections;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.Globalization;
      using System.Linq;
      using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
      using System.Text;
      using System.Threading.Tasks;
      using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace ConsoleApplication3
 {
class Program
{

    private static ArrayList GetAllWindows()
    {
        var windowHandles = new ArrayList();
        EnumedWindow callBackPtr = GetWindowHandle;
        EnumWindows(callBackPtr, windowHandles);

        foreach (IntPtr windowHandle in windowHandles.ToArray())
        {
            EnumChildWindows(windowHandle, callBackPtr, windowHandles);
        }

        return windowHandles;
    }

    private delegate bool EnumedWindow(IntPtr handleWindow, ArrayList handles);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumedWindow lpEnumFunc, ArrayList lParam);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumedWindow callback, ArrayList lParam);

    private static bool GetWindowHandle(IntPtr windowHandle, ArrayList windowHandles)
    {
        windowHandles.Add(windowHandle);
        return true;
    }

    [DllImport("user32")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr i);

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a list of child windows
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">Parent of the windows to return</param>
    /// <returns>List of child windows</returns>
    public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
    {
        List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
        GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
        try
        {
            EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
            EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                listHandle.Free();
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback method to be used when enumerating windows.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle">Handle of the next window</param>
    /// <param name="pointer">Pointer to a GCHandle that holds a reference to the list to fill</param>
    /// <returns>True to continue the enumeration, false to bail</returns>
    private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
    {
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
        List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
        }
        list.Add(handle);
        //  You can modify this to check to see if you want to cancel the operation, then return a null here
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delegate for the EnumChildWindows method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">Window handle</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">Caller-defined variable; we use it for a pointer to our list</param>
    /// <returns>True to continue enumerating, false to bail.</returns>
    public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr parameter);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
          public static string isIEServerWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        int nRet;
        // Pre-allocate 256 characters, since this is the maximum class name length.
        StringBuilder ClassName = new StringBuilder(256);
        //Get the window class name
        nRet = GetClassName(hWnd, ClassName, ClassName.Capacity);
        if (nRet != 0)
        {
            if (ClassName.ToString() == "TSortGrid")
            {
                GetWindowText(hWnd);
                Console.WriteLine(ClassName + " - " + hWnd);
            }

            return ClassName.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
        return "";
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       isIEServerWindow(new IntPtr(394872));


       ArrayList test=  GetAllWindows();
       foreach (IntPtr tesst in test)
       {
           isIEServerWindow(tesst);

       }
      //  GetChildWindows(new IntPtr(394872));
    }
}
```

}

here im able to get the instance  of the tsortgrid and the hwnd but when im trying to get the content(not the caption or length but the text rows and column names and cell content of reason column) its returning me null value.i used this code to get the syslistview32 text

```
    public static object GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        string StrData = "";
        object obj2 = "";
        if (hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            return "";
        }
        SendMessage(hWnd, 0x111, (IntPtr)0x81eb, IntPtr.Zero);
        StrData = StrData + Clipboard.GetText();
        SendMessage(hWnd, 0x307, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        return obj2;
    }
```

but this code is not retrieving the text of TSortGrid.Can you please tell me where am i going wrong ?Thanks in advance

Comment: Are we meant to guess what 0x111 and 0x307 are? What is TSortGrid? Is it a Delphi control that offers no way to extract text?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 273 and 775 .yeah it is a delphi control.I want to extract the data from that control as it updates live data for every second

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake, I don't care what the values are in decimal, what messages are they? Ido know, but the code is opaque. Don't use magic constants.

Comment: I explained you what my problem is clearly.what else do you want me to tell you for heaven's sake?

Answer (score 2):

This control is a Delphi control that offers no automation facilities. It won't respond to those windows messages, and it won't offer anything via UI Automation.

Your options include:

- Screen scraping and OCR.
- Injecting Delphi code into the external process to read the control content natively.
- Reverse engineer the control's data structure and read the contents using `ReadProcessMemory`.

None of these are very attractive.